# Prove that there is a bijection between the space of closed paths in X with base point $x_0$ and the set of continuous functions

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be a topological space and $x_0 \in X $ a point. Prove that there is a bijection between the space of closed paths in X with base point $x_0$ and the set of continuous functions $f: S^1\to X$ such that $f (1) = x_0.$
I don’t know how I have to show that this function is bijective.
Can you help me?

Comment: Do you know any results on quotient spaces?

Comment: I know universal property of quotient space but it doesn’t say nothing about bijection functions

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** firstly prove that $S^1 \equiv [0,1]/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that identifies $0$ with $1$. A closed loop

$$
f : [0,1] \to X
$$

is compatible with $\sim$, meaning that if $x \sim y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$. Now use a result on quotient spaces to obtain a map from the $1$-sphere to $X$. Finally, prove this assignment yields the desired bijection.

**Edit:** suppose that you have an equivalence relation $R$ on a space $X$. We define the quotient space $X/ R$ as the set of equivalence classes of $R$ with the final topology induced by the canonical projection $q : X \to X/R$.  We say $h : X\to Y$ is $R$-compatible if $xRy$ implies $h(x) = h(y)$ for each $x,y \in X$. Now,

> **Proposition.** Let $R$ be a equivalence relation on $X$ and $h : X\to Y$ an $R$-compatible continuous function. Then, there exists a unique continuous function $\widehat{h}: X/R \to Y$ such that $\widehat{h}q = h$.

*Proof.* Let's prove existence first. We define $\widehat{h}([x]) = h(x)$. Note that this is well defined (meaning it does not depend on the representative chosen) precisely because $h$ is $R$-compatible: if $[x] = [y]$ then $xRy$ and so $h(x) = h(y)$.

Recalling that $[x] = q(x)$, we see that moreover $\widehat{h}q = h$. This also proves continuity, because $X/R$ has the final topology with respect to $q$ and $\widehat{h}q$ is continuous by hypothesis.

As for uniqueness, this comes from the fact that $q$ is surjective and therefore right-cancellative: if $gq = h = \widehat{h}q$, then $g = \widehat{h}$. $\ \square$

Back to the original problem: if $f$ is $\sim$-compatible, we have a map $\widehat{f} : [0,1]/\sim \ \longrightarrow \ X$ as in the previous proposition.

**Edit 2:** Note that $[0,1]/\sim  \equiv S^1$ via $g([t]) := e^{ti2\pi}$. We have seen that for each closed loop $f$ we can build a map from $[0,1]/\sim$ to $X$, which I've called $\widehat{f}$. Thus, we can define

$$
\begin{align}
A &= \{\gamma : [0,1] \to X : \text{$\gamma$ is a closed loop based on $x_0$}\} \text{ and }\\
B &= \{f :S^1 \to X : \text{$f$ continuous and $f(1) = x_0$ }\}
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
F : \ &A \to B\\
&f \mapsto \widetilde{f}
\end{align}
$$

where $\widetilde{f} = \widehat{f}g^{-1}$.

(The intuition here is that we pass from a map on $[0,1]$ to one in the interval with glued endpoints, and then $g$ makes this into a map to $S^1$)

Let's see that $F$ is bijective: if $h : S^1 \to X$ is a map from the sphere to $X$, then $hgq$ is a map from $[0,1]$ to $X$. Moreover, by the uniqueness of the universal property it must be $\widehat{hgq} = hg$ and so $F(hgq) = \widetilde{hgq} = hgh^{-1} = h$. This shows that $F$ is surjective.

Finally, if $F(f) = \widehat{f}g^{-1} = \widehat{f'}g^{-1} = F(f')$ then $\widehat{f} = \widehat{f'}$ and so

$$
f = \widehat{f}q = \widehat{f'}q = f'.
$$

To unpack all this,  $g$ maps the interval with the glued ends to the circle, and $\widetilde{f}$ is just the mapping that takes a point $x \in S^1$, which is some point of the form $e^{ti2\pi}$, and outputs $f(t)$.

In a way, the idea here is that $S^1$ is like $[0,1]$ as long as we mentally glue the endpoints. Thus, a map on the circle can be 'flattened' to a map on $[0,1]$ which takes the same value on the $0$ and $1$. Reciprocally, every map from the interval that takes the same value at the endpoints can be made into a map from the circle by 'wrapping $[0,1]$ into $S^1$ (which makes the endpoints overlap, motivating this sort of coherence condition that we've required)'.

Comment: Sorry I know that hint but I don’t know result on quotient spaces to obtain a map from the 1-sphere to X. Can you explain me please?

Comment: @caterina use the universal property

Comment: @Andres Mejia but universal property doesn’t say nothing about bijection functions

Comment: @caterina this is, after all, just a hint. I'm not providing you a result that gives a bijection. I'm only describing the mapping that you should check is bijective. For completeness I've included the result on quotient spaces I was referring to.

Comment: I don’t understand

Comment: @caterina well, what universal property do you know?

Comment: *what* exactly? I don't mind helping, but I can't *guess* what you're not understanding...

Comment: Also, I've included a version of this universal property in the post just to make the argument self-contained.

Comment: In my exercise the hint is inclused. I know that :[0,1]/∼ ⟶  is continuous for universal property of quotient topology but I don’t know how I have to use this for show that function is a bijection

Comment: Okay. We have produced a mechanism that assigns each closed loop $f : [0,1] \to X$ a function $\widehat{f} : S^1 \to X$. The result on quotients was only used to define this assignment. Now you have to prove that $f \mapsto \widehat{f}$ is bijective. **Hint 2:** remember that $\widehat{f}$ is the **only** continuous function that satisfies $\widehat{f}q = f$.

Comment: Okay now how Have I to show that f^ is a bijection?

Comment: This is my problem.

Comment: No, you have to show that $F(f) = \widehat{f}$ is a bijection. I'll include a solution, but I encourage you to think about this a bit more.

Comment: Sorry but it is from yesterday that I try to do this exercise but I have not succeeded. please help me if you have the solution

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If $p:[0,1]\to X$ is a closed path with base point $x_0$, then $F(p): S^1 \to X$ can be defined by $F(p)(e^{2\pi it})= p(t)$, where $t \in [0,1)$.

$p \to F(p)$ is a bijection between your sets. If $p \neq p'$ they differ on some $t' \in [0,1]$ and then $F(p)$ and $F(p')$ differ on $e^{2\pi it'}$ and so are different loops.

And if $q: S^1 \to X$ is a loop with $q(1) = x_0$, just define $p(t) = q(e^{2\pi it})$ and check that $p$ is well-defined and $F(p) =q$, so we have ontoness.

Comment: Because that function is a bijection?